# FFmpeg is slowing down a video in output and I cannot figure out why

Tags: numpy, ffmpeg

I'm making a python program that uses FFmpeg for I/O. Right now the problem I'm getting is an input video is 3s but output is 9s. Both line up if I stretch them out manually in premiere pro but I want to fix this with ffmpeg. I know my array is 223 frames and I only give FFmpeg the argument "-r 60", but when the command is run and the video is made, it repeats every frame about 3 times, making the resulting video much longer. I can't just add command to make it play video 3 times faster because its not exactly 3 (I don't know what the exact multiplier for difference is). Is there anything I can do to make it not repeat frames?

Edit: I'm using skvideo.vwrite so I'm not really sure what's happening with FFmpeg but this is the code I have:
skvideo.io.vwrite("out.mp4", arr, outputdict = {'-r':'60'})
Where arr has shape (854, 256, 256, 3)

Comment: Show your command and the complete log.

Comment: The thing is, I'm using a wrapper for it so I have no way of actually knowing what the FFmpeg command being run is. The library im using (scikit video) just provides a vwrite function that takes a dictionary of ffmpeg commands. That's why all I can say about it is the commands I'm passing. Which is just "-r 60".

Comment: If you can add -report as an option, ffmpeg will generate a report file, which includes its command.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Problem was with skvideo, not FFmpeg. Putting commands for output in skvideo does nothing because the problem is that it interprets the array you put in as being 25 fps and works from that. Solution is to add "inputdict = {'-r' : FPS}" where FPS is a string for the fps you want (i.e. '60' or '30') in vwrite.